# Content for '★' in CSS appears as 'â˜…'

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:

```
.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
  content: '★';
}
```

And when being rendered, instead of a `★` I see `â˜`.  If I use Firebug and I change the content to ★, it shows correctly.

What can be happening? How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably the text encodings (character sets) for your CSS and HTML files do not agree.

To set a stylesheet's encoding, use `@charset`; for example:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

To set an HTML page's encoding, use a `<meta>` tag (in the `<head>` section at the top); for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

or in HTML 5:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

The `@charset` of a stylesheet *must* agree with the encoding chosen for its HTML page.

Comment: Note that AFAIK http-equiv `<meta>` headers are only honored for `file://` access; the actual HTTP headers supplied by the web server are what count for `http://`. Also, note that for HTML5 specifically you can type simply: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: The encodings need not be the same. What matters is that the encoding is properly declared.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the BLACK STAR “★” (U+2605) appears as UTF-8 encoded in the source that contains the CSS code, but that source is being interpreted as ISO-8859-1 encoded. The fix depends on where the CSS code is, on the server software, etc.

See [Declaring character encodings in CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset).

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify it in its hexadecimal value, without adding the character encoding declaration.

Instead of:

```
content: '★';
```

it should be:

```
content: '\2605';
```

You can look it up here:

https://graphemica.com/%E2%98%85

Answer (score 0):

In the slick-theme.css file i had : `@charset 'UTF-8'` , the single quote marks where the problem , i changed them to double quotes like so : `@charset "UTF-8"`. And it worked